# how to make use of data that unknown in the future?

Tags: r, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy

I have 2 datasets. df1 stores the data about the restaurant, df2 is weather data.

```
df1 
       date  how many customers came  Sales($)  how many pokes used (kg) ...
0  20180101                     120     44520                       58
1  20180102                     270     57950                       60
2  20180103                     290     65320                       90
...

df2 
       date  temperature  precipitation ...
0  20180101           35          0.2
1  20180102           23          0.5
2  20180103           31          0.6
...
```

I want to make a model that can predict how many pokes will be used in the future day.

I can't know how many customers will come, and how many sales will be in the future. So I only use the weather data to build a model.

I tried to use the weather data to predict `sales` and use weather data and predicted `sales` data to predict `how many pocks used`, but the score even worse than the model that only use weather data.

Is there any way to make use of other data in `df1`?

Comment: Just merge the 2 data.frames by date and use any number of variables as predictors in your model. Anything I'm missing in your question?

Comment: @Simon Sorry, I have edited my question. I want to make a model that can predict how many pokes will be used in the future day. I can use the weather forecast data. But the data like `sales` will not know until that day comes.

Comment: If you have some past history, it's also worth looking at trends in the data -- many time series have weekly and annual periodicity. You might get something from this free online textbook:   https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two dataframes on `date` feature and train the model on the features that will be known to you in the future. This will be your first method. You havent mentioned what other features will look like so we cannot really mention which features might be important and if you should use any data normalization or scaling methods.

Your second method will be to train a model based on the weather data and try to predict the number of customers and then use the weather data along with predicted customer data to create a model. This particular method is quite risky because a small error in customer prediction might result in major changes in the `pokes` prediction.

Also mention, which ML model you are currently using to make the predictions as not every model works with every dataset.